# can we set blockperiodseconds to be less that one seconds?

Tags: quorum

I am using the consensys quorum to make internal blockchain.

the latency of the blockchain is very high and I want to make it faster

https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/configure-and-manage/configure/consensus-protocols/ibft

I want to change the block time to be lower as described below to be less than 1 second.
But I found that this might be expressed in uint64 that may not accept decimal.
https://github.com/Consensys/quorum/blob/fbfb5dd12a8c2b8abd053f858ef539ab38196b75/params/config.go#L414C1-L414C1

[image]